# PHP POST Request Special Characters

Tags: php, post, request

I'm trying to send a special character, such as `ñ`, through a POST request in PHP. When I do it, it comes out as `Ã±`, what is wrong and how do I fix it?

I'm sending and receiving the post request in PHP, here is what I use to send it:

```
$url = '<url>';
$data = array('key' => 'ñ');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $result;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The encoding of the ouput is different from the encoding of the input and you've not translated it. But you've not shown us the relevant bits of http which control the encoding.

Comment: @symcbean For the output, I just do this in PHP: `echo $_POST['key'];` and it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem receiving wrong character can be dealed with mb_detect_encoding() and mb_convert_encoding() functions.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto so rather than doing `echo $_POST['key'];`, I do `echo mb_convert_encoding($_POST['key'], "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($_POST['key']);` and it'll work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$data = array('key' => urlencode('ñ'));
```

And in the `$url` file:

```
$_POST['key']=urldecode($_POST['key']);
```

This is how I use to send special characters in GET and POST method with ajax, it must work for php too.